# Spring data elastic search with Java high level rest client

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

I am a beginner in Elastic search and looking for best way to integrate elastic search with Spring boot.

I am not sure which of the following to use:-

- Spring data elastic search
- JEST
- Java high level rest client

Thanks

Comment: look at https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-data-jest

Answer (score 8):

It depends on how you want to interact with ES.

If you want to use an ORM on top of Elasticsearch to perform CRUD operations on documents, then Spring Data Elasticsearch is the way to go. Beware, though, Spring Data ES lags a bit behind the latest ES releases, so depending on your ES version, it might be more difficult to integrate Spring Data ES (via Spring Boot).

The other two are more general purpose clients, which allow you to do pretty much anything with ES.

JEST is a good choice and has been one of my favorite for a long time since Elasticsearch lacked a real good REST client.

The Java High-Level REST client is getting more traction as Elastic puts more effort into it (since the transport client is doing to disappear). The big advantage of this one is that it is the official REST client supported by Elastic and offers a good integration with the request/response DSL, which JEST doesn't.

**UPDATE**

To integrate the REST client with Spring Boot, you can do it like any other dependency, like this, create a configuration bean and then autowire the dependency wherever you need:

```
/** Configuration Bean */
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public RestClient restClient() {
        return RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port)).build();
    }
}

// use the dependency in your other components/services, using dependency injection
@Autowired
private RestClient restClient;
```

Comment: Thank you Val, I am planning to use Java High-Level REST client after studying a lot. But i couldn't find a way forward on how to integrate it with Spring boot?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Hi Val, I have encountered one more doubt though Java high level rest client is good enough but it the client need to be have the same version as of Elastic search version and there is no support for Elastic search 5.x. will JESt support all ES opeartions irevalant to Elastic search version??

Comment: It is irrelevant whether jest supports all operations or not. What you need to figure out is whether Jest supports the operations you need. It is easy to find out by looking at their documentation and source code.

Comment: Hi Val, I want to do only indexing of data irrespective of ES version. I have tried to integrate Java high level rest client with Spring as well,but unable to resolve dependency properly.
I even tried Logstash but my use case requires filtering of data where i need to get message from Rabbitmq filter it and index it ES.
Could you please guide me to get a better way to perform this task??

Thanks for your help and support..

Comment: @PujaBarad are you abel to resolve this issue?