# Elasticsearch Spring Data with RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I don't understand the relationship between the High Level REST CLient (which replaces the Transport Client) and Spring Data Elasticsearch.

There are tutorials (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-tutorial) showing how to make JPA-style queries with auto-implemented methods like getSomethingById(). They utilize this interface:

```
public interface ElasticsearchRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<T, ID> {
```

But `ElasticsearchRepository` seems to require a `@Configuration`-Class with an ElasticsearchTemplate-Bean and that requires the TransportClient. As far as I have tried out, there is no way of replacing it with the High/Low Level Java Rest Clients, no?

So if I want to use the newest official Client, there is no JPA-goodness for me?

Comment: There's an open issue regarding this in the Spring Data ES repo: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-407

Comment: @Val Thank you very much! I also appreciated your answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172625/spring-data-elastic-search-with-java-high-level-rest-client Really useful information there!

Comment: @Val can you please post your comment as answer. I'm tired of reading questions that are already answered in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an open issue regarding this in the Spring Data ES repo: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-407

Comment: seems that 3.2 M1 includes the porting toward High Level REST Client; ipiii :)

Comment: @adrhc looks like the 3.2 M1 release is delayed. It was scheduled to release in Dec 2018

Answer (score 1):

spring-data-elasticsearch 3.2.0, now available as M2 contains the code to use the RestClient.

See my answer to this question: [What Elasticsearch client does Spring-Data-Elasticsearch use under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54981698/what-elasticsearch-client-does-spring-data-elasticsearch-use-under-the-hood/55481682) for how to set it up

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Moore has been release  including this feature (October 8 2019).This is the main description:

```
Elasticsearch: High Level REST Client support & non Jackson based entity mapping
```

If yo need more detail You will be able to have a look to this jira issue:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-407 for more detail